# Look up and replace partial values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements, lookup

I have list A, which contains values separated by "|" and looks like this

```
df1['original']= ['aaa|bbb|ccc','aaa|ccc','aaa|ccc|ddd']
```

output:

```
aaa|bbb|ccc
aaa|ccc
aaa|ccc|ddd
```

In another df, I have another two columns.  First one looks like this:           `df1['title']=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']`. 
And correspondingly, I have another column next to df1['title'].
`df1['new_value']=['x','y','z','w']`.

output:

```
title new_value
aaa      x
bbb      y
ccc      z
ddd      w
```

I want to search every value in `df1['original']` and replace by the searching results based on `df1['title']` and `df1['new_value']`. I want to keep the`|` in the original column. And the final output should look like this:

```
df1['New']=['x|y|z','x|z','x|z|w']
```

output:
New

```
x|y|z
x|z
x|z|w
```

This is more like a conditional lookup in excel and any ideas how to achieve this in python?

Thanks for your time!

The link below can only match the ones that contain one value.
Look up and replace values in a list (pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us using `replace`

```
df1['New']=df1.original.replace(df2.set_index('title').new_value.to_dict(),regex=True)
df1
Out[758]: 
      original    New
0  aaa|bbb|ccc  x|y|z
1      aaa|ccc    x|z
2  aaa|ccc|ddd  x|z|w
```

Comment: What is `df2` in this case?

Comment: @dawg *In another df*, I think that is op's input, Am i right ?

Comment: Well it looks promising but the examples given are all columns in `df1`... But his example may be wrong too ;-)

Comment: @dawg I got what you say ..:-)

Comment: Hey Wen, this works great. I was trying to understand this code. Can you please explain a bit? Especially this part: df2.set_index('title').new_value.to_dict().

Comment: @LangkengWang make your df2 to a dict  you can check pandas dataframe to dict:-)

Comment: @Wen thx for the reply again. I got that, so that code is setting the df2['new_value'] column to a dict. But how did the replace work? The code is saying replace the 'original' column by using the dict we just defined?

Comment: @LangkengWang replace can pass a dict :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this evil hack using the `format` method?

```
In = ['aaa|bbb|ccc','aaa|ccc','aaa|ccc|ddd']
replace = 'aaa x bbb y ccc z ddd w'
# use the infamous grouper (if you have keys and values in separate
# lists you don't need this) to get a dict:
replace = iter(replace.split())
replace = dict(zip(*2*(replace,)))
# enclose all templates with curlies 
# like 'aaa|bbb|ccc' -> '{aaa}|{bbb}|{ccc}'
# and use .format
Out = [('{' + s.replace('|', '}|{') + '}').format(**replace) for s in In]
# ['x|y|z', 'x|z', 'x|z|w']
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your reply. Can you extend this to a loop, please? Coz i actually have a big data set and that was just a small example. I am new to python.

Comment: If you have all your input in a list you do not need am´n explicit loop. The output is created by a so called [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension). Try a huge list for `In`. The code should work without change.

Answer (score 0):

In Python only, methodically, you can do:

Create the dict (which is really similar to a Pandas data frame):

```
df1={}
df1['original']= ['aaa|bbb|ccc','aaa|ccc','aaa|ccc|ddd']
df1['title']=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']
df1['new_value']=['x','y','z','w']
```

Create a dict of the old mapped to the new:

```
di=dict(zip(df1['title'], df1['new_value']))
```

Create the new dict entry described:

```
nl=[]
for sl in [s.split('|') for s in df1['original']]:
    nl.append([di[e] for e in sl])

df1['New']=['|'.join(e) for e in nl]
# {'New': ['x|y|z', 'x|z', 'x|z|w'],...}
```

Comment: Hey dawg, when you create the dict, in this case u can type all the inputs manually, but i actually have a very big dataset. How should i create dict in that case? Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Just use the columns in the data frame. The entries in my manual dict should work almost the same.